# Why does Socket use streams but NIO SocketChannel use read/write?

Tags: java, sockets, nio

I'm experimenting with writing a non-blocking client/server of which I've noticed that Socket provides `getInputStream()` and `getOutputStream()` but SocketChannel provides `read()` and `write()`.

The following questions are all related and is an effort to better understand the situation:

- Why do these objects differ in how the packet data is provided?
- Is this a side-effect of blocking vs non-blocking or simply a differing
  in implementation?
- Is this something I need to consider while deciding how to read from the socket?
- Can I receive an incomplete packet where the buffer ends earlier than expected in either implementation?

Comment: There is no such thing as an 'NIO Socket'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do these objects differ in how the packet data is provided?

Because otherwise they would be the same. The designers of NIO felt that they had to encapsulate data, position, capacity, and limit into a single class.

> Is this a side-effect of blocking vs non-blocking or simply a differing in implementation?

No and yes.

> Is this something I need to consider while deciding how to read from the socket?

Of course.

> Can I receive an incomplete packet where the buffer ends earlier than expected in either implementation?

Yes. This is a property of TCP/IP, not of Java.