# What is the preferred way to read from a SocketChannel?

Tags: java, sockets, nio

I'm experimenting with writing a non-blocking client/server of which I've noticed that Socket provides `getInputStream()` and `getOutputStream()` but SocketChannel provides `read()` and `write()`.

I would like to access the packet with a `ByteArrayDataInput` of which I could use the following in blocking mode:

`ByteStreams.newDataInput(socket.getInputStream().read());`

But if I attempt to do so in non-blocking mode I get the following error:

`java.nio.channels.IllegalBlockingModeException`

From what I understand, I must read the packet through the channel which provides only `read()` and `write()`.

What is the preferred way to get at this data in a similar fashion to `ByteArrayDataInput` where I can read either raw types or UTF8 strings?

My NIO thread is as follows:

```
while (true) {
   try {
      int num;

      try {
         // Blocking
         num = selector.select();
      }
      catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();

         continue;
      }

      if (num == 0)
         continue;

      Set<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys();
      Iterator<SelectionKey> it = keys.iterator();

      while (it.hasNext()) {
         SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey)it.next();

         // Client requires a connection
         if (key.isAcceptable()) {
            System.out.println("Socket connected!");

            ServerSocketChannel ssc = (ServerSocketChannel)key.channel();
            SocketChannel sc;

            try {
               sc = (SocketChannel)ssc.accept();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();

               ssc.close();
               continue;
            }

            sc.configureBlocking(false);
            sc.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
         }

         if (key.isReadable()) {
            SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel)key.channel();

            // Read from the socket channel here
         }
      }

      keys.clear();
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you read any documentation or tutorials about non-blocking IO? It's a bit trickier than blocking IO, and you seem to be pretty lost about both of them.

Comment: I have but a lot of the tutorials either talk about working with streams (blocking) or provide trivial examples for NIO that do not provide insight into using `read()` for packets with variable data types.

Comment: That's because the non-blocking nature makes it harder to work with the data in the way that you're hoping to. I recommend either using blocking IO or using a library that abstracts NIO away from you, like netty. Of course if you do want to do it yourself, prepare to do a lot of reading and don't hope for any simple examples.

Comment: This is an exersize in working with NIO. I would like to understand how to work with this to better understand what is going on. I have some related questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40728102/why-does-nio-socket-use-streams-but-socketchannel-use-read-write